# Invoke-WebRequest Proxy Authentication Error

Tags: powershell, proxy, powershell-3.0, squid

I am trying to use an HTTP proxy I purchased from *TorGuard* with PowerShell. I am able to successfully connect to the proxy server however it returns a **Cache Access Denied** Error message. My script is:

```
$url = "http://www.foo.org/"
$request = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url `
           -Proxy "http://web.proxy.torguard.org:6060" -ProxyCredential $myCreds
```

The complete error message returned is:

> The following error was encountered while trying to retrieve the URL: http://www.foo.org/
>
> Cache Access Denied.
>
> Sorry, you are not currently allowed to request http://www.foo.org/ from this cache until you have authenticated yourself.
>   Please contact the cache administrator if you have difficulties authenticating yourself.
>
> Generated Sat, 05 Sep 2015 16:07:20 GMT by 91.233.116.119 (squid/3.1.23)

The same error message is returned regardless of the value of `$url`.

This is what TorGuard support said:

> It sounds like it’s not submitting the form.

Am I missing a parameter in my `Invoke-WebRequest`?

Comment: How are you creating `$myCreds`? Is it a PSCredential object?

Comment: Yes it is. It seems to be working.